# Sitecore 9.3 Serialization CLI failing to push

Tags: sitecore, sitecore9.3

We have a sitecore 9.3 project which is not helix and also not headless.
I am trying to add serialization cli, I have installed cli and management services (v. 5.1.25).
dotnet tool restore and authentication works fine.
But when I try to push 'dotnet siteore ser push', it finds all the items that needs to be added but then in the end right after "Applying changes...", it throws an error.

The error is as below;

*[GraphQLException] GraphQL.ExecutionError: An exception occurred while processing the request. ---> System.MissingFieldException: Field not found: 'Sitecore.DevEx.Serialization.Logging.SerializationEventIds.Created'.
at Sitecore.DevEx.GraphQL.Serialization.Mutations.SerializationCommands.CreateItemCommand.Execute(SerializationCommandData command, IItemData dataModel)
at Sitecore.DevEx.GraphQL.Serialization.Mutations.SerializationCommands.CommandExtensions.TryExecute(IEnumerable`1 commands, IList`1& results)
at Sitecore.DevEx.GraphQL.Serialization.Mutations.ExecuteSerializationCommandsMutation.Resolve(ResolveFieldContext context)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
[GraphQLException] GraphQL.ExecutionError: Cannot return null for non-null type. Field: name, Type: String!.
at GraphQL.Execution.ExecutionStrategy.ValidateNodeResult(ExecutionContext context, ExecutionNode node)
at GraphQL.Execution.ExecutionStrategy.d__7.MoveNext()
[GraphQLException] GraphQL.ExecutionError: Error trying to resolve logLevel. ---> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel Sitecore.DevEx.Logging.OperationMessage.get_LogLevel()'.
at Sitecore.DevEx.GraphQL.Serialization.GraphTypes.OperationResultMessageGraphType.ResolveLevel(ResolveFieldContext`1 context) at GraphQL.Resolvers.FuncFieldResolver`2.GraphQL.Resolvers.IFieldResolver.Resolve(ResolveFieldContext context)
at GraphQL.Execution.ExecutionStrategy.d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
[GraphQLException] GraphQL.ExecutionError: Error trying to resolve eventID. ---> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventId Sitecore.DevEx.Logging.OperationMessage.get_EventId()'.
at Sitecore.DevEx.GraphQL.Serialization.GraphTypes.OperationResultMessageGraphType.ResolveEventId(ResolveFieldContext`1 context) at GraphQL.Resolvers.FuncFieldResolver`2.GraphQL.Resolvers.IFieldResolver.Resolve(ResolveFieldContext context)
at GraphQL.Execution.ExecutionStrategy.d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---*

Does anyone have experience this? any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid Sitecore CLI and Content Serialization are only compatible with Sitecore version 10 and newer.

Sitecore CLI and Content Serialization was a brand new feature when Sitecore 10 was released. Please refer to Sitecore 10 [release notes](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform/100/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform%20100/Release%20Notes) and Sitecore module compatibility tables for [version 9](https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0541788) and [version 10](https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB1000576). Your version of Management Services (v. 5.1.25) is supported by 10.1+. You can try it with an older version but I think Sitecore will not provide any support for these modules installed on Sitecore 9.3.

Please consider using [Unicorn](https://github.com/SitecoreUnicorn/Unicorn) or [Sitecore TDS](https://www.teamdevelopmentforsitecore.com/Download/TDS-Classic) for content serialisation, they both have versions that are compatible with Sitecore 9.3.